# CUPS: How to set staples for a printer?

Tags: cups

I don't find the option into the CUPS web for the options of the printer. Is it possible from the command line?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should probably add some more information, such as what printer it is, and what environment you're running it in.

Comment: Hi, but the command (probably lpadmin) is generic, if the printer allows staples it should work. Best regards.